# In HP, how does Stupefy work?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

In *HP*, I don't really understand how *Stupefy* works. It can't be permanent because then would basically be death, and in my understanding, *Stupefy* only makes people faint/go unconscious. However, at some point, a gnome is Stupefied to be an angel on the Weasleys' Christmas tree, and there is no mention of them having to repeat the spell, because it says that no one besides Fred, George, Ron, and Harry knew that the "angel" was actually a gnome. So how does *Stupefy* work?

Comment: It supposedly wears down over time, so the gnome would've woken up at some point. But the duration of the spell is unknown, so...

Comment: Different creatures respond differently to spells. Giants (including half-giants) and dragons are resistant to stunning, so conversely gnomes might be susceptible.

Comment: Also you don't know if Fred and George are repeatedly stunning their gnome whenever it wakes up.

Comment: They might have used Petrificus Totalus on it after having used Stupefy on it

Answer (score 3):

## The effects of Stupefy do wear off in time.

In Number Twelve Grimmauld Place, Molly Weasley casts Stupefy on all the portraits in the hall to silence them.

> “Tonks apologised over and over again, dragging the huge, heavy troll’s leg back off the floor; Mrs Weasley abandoned the attempt to close the curtains and hurried up and down the hall, Stunning all the other portraits with her wand; and a man with long black hair came charging out of a door facing Harry.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 4 (Number Twelve, Place)*</sup></sub>

Sirius expects that it will not last, because he tells Harry they should get downstairs before the portraits awaken.

> “Let’s get downstairs, quick, before they all wake up again.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 5 (The Order of the Phoenix)*</sup></sub>

Indeed, the portraits are shrieking again the next day.

> “Mrs Weasley’s voice was lost amid fresh shrieks and screams from the portraits in the hall.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 6 (The Noble and Most Ancient House of Black)*</sup></sub>

No one would have intentionally reawakened the portraits, so therefore the Stunning Spells on them wore off.

## Fred and George likely kept casting it.

To keep the gnome on top of the Christmas tree, presumably Fred and George would just need to keep casting Stupefy on it when the others were not looking. Stupefy can be repeatedly cast on the same individual.

> “Can’t we kidnap Mrs Norris?’ Ron suggested during Monday lunchtime, as he lay flat on his back in the middle of their Charms classroom, having just been Stunned and re-awoken by Harry for the fifth time in a row. ‘Let’s Stun her for a bit.” 
> <sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 29 (The Dream)*</sup>

All Fred and George would have to do is to keep the gnome Stupefied until the Weasleys took their Christmas tree down.

Comment: You could add a bit about how stupefy affects different creatures, since that seems to be pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

Stupefy is a stunning spell and has different effects based on the context, target and amplification with which it is used. The effect of the spell wears off, but I am not sure if it is mentioned in the books. I had read it in potter more long time back.

I do agree it can be confusing.

***Living Entities***

**Humans:** The spell can render a target unconscious without causing lasting damage.

> “Stupefy!” Harry yelled.
>
> The spell hit Krum in the back; he stopped dead in his tracks, fell forward, and lay motionless, facedown in the grass. Harry dashed over to Cedric, who had stopped twitching and was lying there panting, his hands over his face.”
>
> Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 31, The Third Task

**Dragons: Have resistance to the spell**

> “It’s no good!” yelled another wizard. “Stunning Spells, on the count of three!”
>   Harry saw each of the dragon keepers pull out his wand.
>
> “Stupefy!” they shouted in unison, and the Stunning Spells shot into the darkness like fiery rockets, bursting in showers of stars on the dragons’ scaly hides —
>
> Harry watched the dragon nearest to them teeter dangerously on its back legs; its jaws stretched wide in a silent howl; its nostrils were suddenly devoid of flame, though still smoking — then, very slowly, it fell. Several tons of sinewy, scaly-black dragon hit the ground with a thud that Harry could have sworn made the trees behind him quake.”
>
> Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 19, The Hungarian Horntail

**Giants and Part Giants: Bounces off them**

> Hagrid’s door had burst open and by the light flooding out of the cabin they saw him quite clearly, a massive figure roaring and brandishing his fists, surrounded by six people, all of whom, judging by the tiny threads of red light they were casting in his direction, seemed to be attempting to Stun him.
>
> But nobody was paying the slightest attention to their star charts anymore: Jets of red light were still flying beside Hagrid’s cabin, yet somehow they seemed to be bouncing off him. He was still upright and still, as far as Harry could see, fighting.
>
> Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 31, O.W.L.S

**Spell Amplification: Can kill humans!**

> “I need to see Professor McGonagall,” gasped Harry, the breath tearing his lungs. “Now … It’s urgent. …”
>
> “She’s not here, Potter,” said Madam Pomfrey sadly. “She was transferred to St. Mungo’s this morning. Four Stunning Spells straight to the chest at her age? It’s a wonder they didn’t kill her.
>
> Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 32, Out of the Fire

***Non living entities***

**Destroy Things**

> “Stupefy!” There was a blinding flash of red light, and with a great splintering and crashing, the door of Moody’s office was blasted apart.
>
> Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 35, Veritaserum

**Slow down Moving objects**

> “Hurry, Filch, hurry!” shrieked Umbridge. “They’ll be all over the school unless we do something — Stupefy!”
>
> A jet of red light shot out of the end of her wand and hit one of the rockets. Instead of freezing in midair, it exploded with such force that it blasted a hole in a painting of a soppy-looking witch in the middle of a meadow — she ran for it just in time, reappearing seconds later squashed into the painting next door, where a couple of wizards playing cards stood up hastily to make room for her.
>
> Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 28, Snape’s Worst Memory

Answer (score 0):

The effects of the Stupefy charm depend on the source (casting wizard/witch,) intended purpose and strength, and the target, among other factors. Generally when the charm is directed to a human or normal sized magical creature the effects are temporary unconsciousness (duration depending on the strength of the charm and the target's defenses/awareness.) A garden gnome is a small creature that does not possess much mental fortitude (that we are aware of) and as such if the intent of the charm was to immobilize the gnome to be used as an ornament it is conceivable that the effects would last as long as necessary for that usage. When multiple wizards/witches cast the charm simultaneously at the same target it can be dangerous, for example when five Ministry employees stunned McGonagall as in Book 5 (it was considered a miracle she survived.) Against larger creatures such as dragons, trolls, giants, and even half-giants (Hagrid) Stupefy may have little to no effect. If one wishes to counteract the effects of a normal Stunning Spell, the counter-charm is *Rennervate*, the Reviving Spell. Apparently Stupefy can also be used to halt the motion of inanimate objects.

[Source info](https://harry-potter-compendium.fandom.com/wiki/Stunning_Spell)